# How to anchor a UIImage correctly into UIView located in a Custom Cell?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uiview, autolayout

So I created a custom cell for my `UITableViewController`. In this Custom Cell I create a UIView which I give a `UIImageView` and a `UILabel`. The problem that I have is that the image appears behind my `UIView`. Both the container for the `UIImageView` and the `UILabelView` are in the correct place, but when I pass the `UIImage` onto the `UIImageView`, the image appears in the back and does not take it rightful place despite the anchoring.

Current Results:
I gave the `UIViews, UIImageView`, and `UILabel` a background color to show where they are placed. Attached is a screenshot of how it currently looks.

In the Screen Shot.

[image]

### Pink Square is the `UIImageView`.

### Green Rectangle is the `UILabel`.

### Blue Rectangle is the UIView where both the `UIImageView` and `UILabel` are anchored too.

The image is behind those views.

```
class CustomCell: UITableViewCell{
var cellView: UIView = {
    var cellV = UIView()
    cellV.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 0, green: 0, blue: 170, alpha: 0.8)
    cellV.addShadow()
    return cellV
}()

var mainImage: UIImageView = {
    var img = UIImageView()
    img.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
    img.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 110, green: 0, blue: 12, alpha: 0.3)
    return img
}()

var imageLabel: UILabel = {
    var lbl = UILabel()
    lbl.backgroundColor = .green
    return lbl
}()


override init(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
    super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
    setUp()
}

func setUp(){
    self.addSubview(cellView)
    cellView.addSubview(mainImage)
    cellView.addSubview(imageLabel)

    cellView.anchor(top: self.topAnchor,
                     leading:self.leadingAnchor,
                     bottom: self.bottomAnchor,
                     trailing: self.trailingAnchor,
                     centerXaxis: nil,
                     centerYaxis: nil,
                     padding: .init(top: 4, left: 8, bottom: 4, right: 8))

    mainImage.anchor(top: nil,
                     leading: cellView.leadingAnchor,
                     bottom: nil,
                     trailing: nil,
                     centerXaxis: nil,
                     centerYaxis: cellView.centerYAnchor,
                     padding: .init(top: 2, left: 2, bottom: 2, right: 0),
                     size: .init(width: 55, height: 55) )

    imageLabel.anchor(top: cellView.topAnchor,
                      leading: mainImage.trailingAnchor,
                      bottom: cellView.bottomAnchor,
                      trailing: trailingAnchor,
                      centerXaxis: nil,
                      centerYaxis: nil,
                      padding: .init(top: 4, left: 8, bottom: 4, right: 8))

}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
   fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}
```

}

Giving an image to the Custom Cell to display.

```
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    guard let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: customCellID, for: indexPath) as? CustomCell else {fatalError("Couldn't make it work")}
    let profileCard = profile[indexPath.row]
    let path = getDocumentsDirectory().appendingPathComponent(profileCard.mainImage)
    cell.imageView?.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path.path)
    cell.imageLabel.text = profileCard.imageLabel
    return cell
}
```

Comment: Better to use `contentView.addSubview(cellView)` , instead of `self.addSubview(cellView)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are setting the image to the **imageView** of the **cell**. You should set the image of **mainImage** instead:

```
cell.mainImage.image = UIImage(contentsOfFile: path.path)
```

Comment: This was it. I can't believe I missed that. Thank you!

Comment: @OcielLerma If the problem is solved accept the answer